# c: macro to initialize new typedef'd object

Tags: c, macros, typedef

I defined a new type:

```
#define MAX_ELEM 10
typedef struct my_type {
   int v[MAX_ELEM];
} my_type;
```

So now, when I declare a new object of this type, I'd like to initialize it to default values:

```
my_type m = MY_TYPE_INIT();
```

I could have something like this:

```
#define MY_TYPE_INIT(m) \
   do { \
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < MAX_ELEM; i++)  \
          m->v[i] = -1;
   } while (0)
```

But I'd like to initialize the way I showed earlier, by assigning values directly to an object of type `my_type`. Is it possible do so?
Thanks.

Comment: Any reason not to use a function for this?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons, I saw this kind of trick before in Linux kernel for example and somewhere else, but can't recall details. I think from the API user point of view, this way (I want) is straightforward and intuitive. Am I wrong?

Comment: `#define MY_TYPE_INIT {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}` and `my_type m = MY_TYPE_INIT;` If you need a loop, use a function.

Comment: You may have seen something like `pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;`

Comment: This would be a lot cleaner if your default values were just `0` instead of `-1`. Can't you just shift how the indexing is used on those values?

Comment: @user3386109 thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

> I could have something like this:
>
> ```
> #define MY_TYPE_INIT(m) \
>    do { \
>       int i;
>       for (i = 0; i < MAX_ELEM; i++)  \
>           m->v[i] = -1;
>    } while (0)
> ```

No, you could not.  Packaging it in a macro does not allow you to put `do` or `for` statements or executable blocks into an initializer.

You *can* define macros to serve as initializers.  They can even be function-like ones.  But they must expand to valid initializers for the type with which you use them.

Macros do not easily do counting or iteration, especially without an upper bound.  Your cleanest ways forward are either to write out the initializer, and update it if ever `MAX_ELEM` changes:

```
#define MY_TYPE_INIT { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 }

// ...

my_type mt = MY_TYPE_INIT;
```

or to write an initialization function:

```
void init_my_type(my_type *mt) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ELEM; i++) {
        m->v[i] = -1;
    }
}

// ...

my_type mt;

// Note: must be inside a function:
init_my_type(&mt);
```